# Custom marker from geojson with multiple geometries

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have a leaflet map with an overlay made from a geojson file that contains polygons, lines and points. I'd like to be able to use custom markers (let's say the image marker is CustomMarker.png). So far, I have the following code that works perfectly well, the only thing is that it displays standard marker icons :

```
$.getJSON(url, function(geojson) {
            overlay = L.geoJson(geojson, {
                style: function(feature) {
                    return {
                        fillColor: 'red',
                        weight: 1,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        color: 'red',
                        dashArray: 3,
                        fillOpacity: 0.5,
                    }
                },
                onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                    layer.bindPopup("<strong>" + layer.feature.properties.Titre + "</strong><br/>" + " : nom de la région")
                }
            }).addTo(map);
```

I know the solution is at my grasp and that something should be put just above "onEachFeature" but can't figure it out so far.

Comment: This is covered by the [Leaflet GeoJSON tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/).

Comment: Actually yes but I don't understand how to attach an image to a point in the very precise javascript configuration above.